# Diagonal stack effect in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a stack of playing cards in CSS, where each card is slightly offset diagonally from the one before it. Here's what it would look like:

```
.card {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: -98px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: -98px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
.card:nth-child(4) {
    margin-left: -98px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}

/* and so on... */
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/coev55w6/

I know I can do it by specifying different margins for each card, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

It's easy enough to create a purely horizontal offset:

```
.card {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.card:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -98px;
}
```

Purely vertical is easy too. But is there a way to get a diagonal offset with only a couple CSS rules?

Comment: As far as I see this is not possible without JS. I think CSS supports only vertical and horizontal flow of elements. And you want kind of both of them to work simultaneously. I can only show you how to achieve this with JS if you want.

Comment: While not currently achievable in CSS, you could use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to make this more manageable.

Comment: @seva.rubbo Thanks, but I can do it in JS myself. Just wanted to know if it was possible to go without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little bit of a hack, but you end up with that effect if you use the second option you gave:

```
.card:not(:first-child)
```

And put a `<br>` after each card:

```
<div>
    <div class=card></div><br>
    <div class=card></div><br>
    <div class=card></div><br>
    <div class=card></div><br>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e4o0k2o5/

You could probably fine-tune it if you used a `line-height` or something other than `<br>`s.

Comment: Awesome. You can also control vertical offset with `line-height`. See http://jsfiddle.net/e4o0k2o5/2/

Comment: Clever! And not hacky enough to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it you're willing or able to change you HTML, but here's a wonderful alternative HTML layout and CSS to achieve your desired card spread.

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.card2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <div class="card2">
      <div class="card2">
        <div class="card2">
          <div class="card2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: But what if you want to manipulate these elements with JS (drag-n-drop them)?

Comment: @seva.rubbo, true, I didn't think of that.  Anyway, it's an alternative, if he doesn't want that.